# Magento get the root category url

Tags: magento

I'm a Magento newbie.

I've customized the top navigation bar and now is something like this:

```
HOME   CATALOG   CMS_LINK   CMS_LINK   CMS_LINK
```

For the `HOME` link and the `CMS_LINK` links all it's ok but I would when an user click on the `CATALOG` will see a page with all categories (subcategories of the root category) in a grid view with category i

Comment: I'd like to know this too - I was thinking "CATALOG" would be a dropdown list as well as being a link to the page as you describe - I was about to make a category called CATALOG then have all the product categories as sub categories of CATALOG as I'm sure that would work, but I then wondered if this was good practice or if there's a better way - I really want to get it right from the start. Anyone?

Answer (score 4):

As part of the category controller action Magento validates the category against the Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category function canShow().

This will return false against the check against isInRootCategoryList(). This function goes and checks the category's parent ids against the store root category id:

```
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
return in_array($rootCategoryId, $category->getParentIds());
```

The easiest solution that I can think of for your problem without changing core functionality would be to create a sub category of your root category named "Catalog" which would itself contain all the other categories. You can then set-up this category to not display products and only display a cms block.